# This Application.Match is returning a type mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

Run-time error '13' (Type mismatch) is returned
The code reads:-

```
TavgRow = Application.Match(ThisStation, ThisSheet.Range("A1:A115083"), 0)
```

where

```
Dim TavgRow As Single
Dim ThisStation As String
```

The range "A1:A115083" is formated as 'Text'.

If I change the code to read:-

```
TavgRow = Application.Match("ITE00100554", ThisSheet.Range("A1:A115083"), 0)
```

it returns without error.

I have tried setting the range to 'General' and the variable 'ThisStation' to 'Variant' but the error persists.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

To give a more full picture of the code:-

```
Do While Not EOF(1)
        
        Input #1, ThisStation
        Input #1, TheDate
            If (ThisStation <> OldStationID Or TheDate <> TheOldDate) And TAVG <> -9999 Then
                
                'Put the data into the spreadsheet and set bits to Zero
                TavgRow = Application.Match(ThisStation, ThisSheet.Range("A1:A115083"), 0)
                TavgColumn = Application.Match(YearMonth, ThisSheet.Range("A1:NE1"), 0)
                
                If TAVG <> 0 Then TAVG = TAVG / 10
                ThisSheet.Cells(TavgRow, TavgColumn) = TAVG
                
                TMAX = -9999
                TMIN = -9999
                TAVG = -9999
            End If
                
            OldStationID = ThisStation
            TheOldDate = TheDate
            
            TheYear = Left(TheDate, 4)
            TheMonth = Mid(TheDate, 5, 2)
            TheDay = Right(TheDate, 2)
            YearMonth = TheDay & "," & TheMonth
```

It all works perfectly except for this one line of code!!!

Comment: Where have you defined `ThisStation`?

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious..You have assigned a value to `ThisStation`, right?

Comment: The first value that it gets assigned is "ITE00100554" which is why I used that as a trial.

Comment: JMP not quite sure how to answer your question other than as given above        Dim ThisStation As String

Comment: We can't see that part in the code you've posted, that's why I'm asking. Are you tracking down the value of `ThisStation`, with a `debug.print` for example, to see what value it has when the code crashes?

Comment: There should be a line that says 'Set ThisStation="ITE00100554"` or similar. Can you post it?

Comment: ThisStation picks up the value  "ITE00100554" in the code line Input #1, ThisStation and debug.print shows it as such

Comment: Have now added a lot more to the code - I hope it helps.

Comment: If you haven't already, adapt Debug.Print to check that no additional spaces are being read in: `Debug.Print "|" & ThisStation & "|"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to force `ThisStation` to be read as a string.

Use:

`TavgRow = Application.Match((ThisStation), ThisSheet.Range("A1:A115083"), 0)`

(with brackets around `ThisStation`) instead.

Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/byref-argument-type-mismatch